# What are the Compatibility issues between MS-OFFICE 2007(Windows) to Open Office on linux?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, microsoft-office, openoffice

I would like to know the compatibility issues between MS-Office 2007 on windows and Open Office on Linux?

Please anybody having thoughts abt this problem,kindly let me know...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Answer (score 2):

The issues can be in saving back an opened ms office 2007 File. And few things are not properly rendered such as nested tables in my case. But remember that OpenOffice is an open one and they are working GREAT to dicipher the CLOSED MS Office formats. So just enjoy the Openness :)

For extra information refer
http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/General/How_do_I_open_Microsoft_Office_2007_files%3F

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/examine-open-offices-interoperability-with-microsoft-office/5083657

Comment: Aren’t the formats documented? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisrae/archive/2010/09/25/where-is-the-documentation-for-office-2010-s-docx-xlsx-pptx-formats.aspx